# spark development on windows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im very new to spark... 
I have set up a standalone cluster using 3 centos vms...
now i want to develope some simple scala program and run it in the cluster...
I am working on windows 7 station without network connection...
I want to use eclis with scala plugin
I have on this computer:scala.msi sbt.msi spark.gz hadoop.gz

what do i do next?
can somwone please instruct me how to start a new simple project in eclipse and create a scala program i can send to the cluster 
i need a detaild instruction from what type of project to create and what refereces to add and how
what project structure to use and how to set it
and how to send it to the cluster

showing me how to do that with both maven and without maven (so i deceide what best fit for me since i working without internet) will be most helpfull

Thanks

Comment: It would be big topic rather than a brief answer. First I'd recommend to check spark deployment guidelines at least from official documentation.

Comment: i succefuuly installed a standaonle cluster... its the dev part that i need help with... just to write a simple program... thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up of cluster then for starting point I suggest you to place text file in hdfs of your cluster and use simple app in order to read words and counts them.
For built you can use Maven-pom or SBT. In order to have less troubles use [ide](http://scala-ide.org/) with scala plugin. The dependency would be org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:{your_version_of_spark}. After packaging your app launch with required params with --master `spark master url`. More details which parameters can be used [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am using IntelliJ and SBT on Windows to build my project but I think the key aspect here is to use a plugin like **sbt-assembly that will build an uber JAR** for you (jar containing all dependencies except spark). Then all you need is to copy that jar to your CentOS cluster and from there run spark-submit with whatever mode (standalone, yarn, client) you need.

Windows requirements:

 See also [spark dev on windows](https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/02/03/how-to-setup-your-first-spark-project-in-intellij-ide/) and [sbt assembly](http://mkuthan.github.io/blog/2016/03/11/spark-application-assembly/)

- IDE (IntelliJ + scala plugin in my case) + SBT + sbt-assembly plugin
- for testing you may
  also want to install spark on windows as well and dont forget to
  install winutils.exe (since you dont run hadoop on Windows)

CentOS requirements:

- Scala + Spark + Hadoop (if needed)

Regarding the use of Maven vs. SBT, my recommendation is use whatever you're familiar with. Personally I find SBT quite concise and easy to use. For your first project just follow the recommendations in www.scala-sbt.org.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already have eclipse with scala plugin , then you can start directly creating maven project . The easiest way to go ahead is to download any sample spark maven project (in scala) from github and import in your eclipse as an existing maven project. 
Instead of running the code in cluster, you can run and check in eclipse itself if you provide .setmaster("local") in spark configuration. This way testing and learning will be more easier . 
Coming to deploying on cluster, you need to create a jar file out of your project (Right click on project->export as jar) and then copy this on to your cluster . Then use spark-submit to submit spark application by specifying master and other configuration settings .

Comment: You don't need to waste time to download and import any sample github project. If using Maven, archetypes have been created